# Getting Wi-Fi on FreeBSD on a PPC Mac

Tags: wifi, freebsd

How do I get Wi-Fi on FreeBSD running on a **PowerPC eMac**? `ifconfig` lists `fwe0`, `gem0` and `lo0` only. The adapter is **Broadcom BCM43xx**. Following [this guide](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) didn't give any Wi-Fi. Also:

> If a wireless adapter is not listed, an additional kernel module might be required, or it might be a model not supported by FreeBSD.

How do I add this additional kernel module mentioned? (Remember, I have no Wi-Fi, but I can transfer files using a USB stick, and I also have a "memory stick" installation of FreeBSD on this.)

(PS! Wi-Fi works when booting OS X 10.5. Here `ifconfig` lists lo0, gif0, stf0, en0, fw0 and en1.)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to find out what WiFi adapter you have. Take a look at the PCI devices

```
# pciconf -lv
```

and at the USB devices

```
# usbconfig list
```

Then take a look at the [FreeBSD 11.2 WiFi HW](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.2R/hardware.html#wlan), or version you want to use. There is also Wiki [DeviceDrivers](https://wiki.freebsd.org/DeviceDrivers) for further information.(Please note, this isn't (yet) an exhaustive list.) More details can be found at [FreeBSD Wireless WIKI](https://wiki.freebsd.org/WiFi)
In my opinion best choice is Atheros, or Intel. And Ralink for USB dongles.

In case of Broadcom BCM43xx you need [bwi](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwi&sektion=4), or [bwn](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwn&sektion=4&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) driver. Find the exact Chip in the manual pages. These drivers should be in your kernel. Find it (in case of bwi)

```
# ll /boot/kernel/ | grep bwi
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    150968 Jun 22 06:24 if_bwi.ko*
```

Load the driver (and all other drivers mentioned in the manual pages) and check *kldstat*. Review details in */var/log/messages* (I have no BCM adapter hence I can't provide you with live example.)

```
# kldload if_bwi
# kldstat | grep bwi
16    1 0xd2a75000 1d000    if_bwi.ko
```

To load the driver on boot add this line into the */boot/loader.conf*

```
if_bwi_load="YES"
```

Probably you'll need some additional "research" about BCM and FreeBSD with respect to you chip. More details are available for example at [BWI driver and firmware](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/bwi-driver-and-firmware.53992/), [BWN Driver Help](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/bwn-driver-help.64290/).

If it's not working in reasonable amount of time I'd advise to find some supported [Ralink USB dongle](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?run(4)). For example this one works fine for me:

```
# usbconfig -d ugen1.3 dump_all_desc
ugen1.3: <Ralink 802.11 n WLAN> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH 
(480Mbps) pwr=ON (450mA)

  bLength = 0x0012 
  bDescriptorType = 0x0001 
  bcdUSB = 0x0200 
  bDeviceClass = 0x0000  <Probed by interface class>
  bDeviceSubClass = 0x0000 
  bDeviceProtocol = 0x0000 
  bMaxPacketSize0 = 0x0040 
  idVendor = 0x148f 
  idProduct = 0x5370 
  bcdDevice = 0x0101 
  iManufacturer = 0x0001  <Ralink>
  iProduct = 0x0002  <802.11 n WLAN>
  iSerialNumber = 0x0003  <1.0>
  bNumConfigurations = 0x0001
```

Comment: Very thorough! I will try this and let you know how it works!